# Statistics for people's shoppings

Tags: statistics

I am building some project (website) on people's shopping (stuff stored in refrigerator) . I need to generate an automatic shopping cart based on people's shopping . 
For example if some person buys every week one bottle of milk , than the website will offer the person to buy milk once a week (if there is no milk in refrigerator) . 
I am storing shopping history of each family. 
But for calculating the shopping cart i need to generate some statistics formula . But i have no clue how to do it. because there might be scenarios (for example birthday) , when the family will buy more products than needed, and it will make me false data for statistics. I want to ignore such scenarios. 
Anyone has idea how and what statistics should i use?

Answer (score 0):

pseudocode

assuming the customer had an account and your database is MySQL

every purchase must save customerid, product id/name ,date of purchase,comment(optional) to a table (e.g. purchased table)

customer has their own table that includes at least their personal info(e.g. customer table)

lets say customer browses the product (viewing the website)

• customer clicks the product

• system/server counts the number of purchase in purchase table

• if the number of purchase is more than one then

```
   - get the last date of purchased product - the current date purchased product = frequency of product needed by date
   - total number of product purchased / total number of times the product purchased = frequency of product needed by item count
```

*UPDATE*

I would suggest that the purchase table has a field that specifies if the current order/purchase is an occasional field instead, so it would be excluded.

example

• system/server counts the number of purchase in purchase table if the purchase is not occasional

Comment: OK. But there might be Standard deviation. for example, a birthday , and the family bought 20 packs of candies. That doesn't mean i buy candies every week ....so how do i exclude these scenarios?

Comment: either use a checkbox or textbox labeled "For Special Occasion"

Comment: I can't do it. i am answering in the aspect of statistics formulas, and not in the design of my website